# Getting an error :org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create HttpClient instance. in tomcat while connecting to solr instance

Tags: jsp, tomcat, solr, solrj

I want to extract data from my solr core and display data on a web page with jsp.

But I am getting above error in tomcat. Following is my .jsp code.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html"%>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import = "java.io.IOException" %>
<%@page import ="org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException" %>
<%@page import = "org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient" %>
<%@page import = "org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse" %>
<%@page import ="org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery" %>
<%@page import = "org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocumentList" %> 

<%
    String cName = (String)request.getParameter("Stellar11");

    HttpSolrClient server = new HttpSolrClient("http://localhost:8983/solr/new1");
    server.getHttpClient();

    SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
    query.setQuery( "*:*" );

    QueryResponse rsp = server.query( query );
    SolrDocumentList docs = rsp.getResults();

    out.print(docs);
%>
```

I am new to jsp. please guide me. thanks in advance.

Comment: are you able to query the same on Solr Admin Console?? and double check your solr index url

Comment: yes . it is working in solr. URL is also correct. This issue is solved. but now i am getting new error as "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient"

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of new to this as well, but I was getting the same error (using solrj via nashorn).

This same exception is discussed at [Missing logging dependency in solrj-lib for SolrJ](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-8180)

There, it seems that the underlying Apache HttpClient is assuming some logging utilities to already be included.  You can probably get your code to work with the slf4j-api library, but the error logging and debugging might not be very useful.  I think the recommended configuration is to use sl4j-simple together with jcl-over-slf4j

All of these logging libraries can be found in a single download from [SLF4J Binary Files](http://www.slf4j.org/download.html)

The SolrJ library has a lot of other dependencies, too.  The HttpSolrClient requires classes that are defined in the Apache httpclient, httpcore, and httpmime jar libraries.  If you're getting "NoClassDefFoundError" exceptions, you might want to import the additional Apache dependencies, as well.

I hope that helps!